# How to wrap a the entire list of matches from HXT with a datatype constructor?

Tags: xml, haskell, hxt

I'm learning [`HXT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt) at the moment by using it to parse a [GPX](http://www.topografix.com/gpx.asp) file. An example is [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c5685c18959cae2b37e6). I've got the following so far:

```
import Data.Time
import Text.XML.HXT.Core

data Gpx    = Gpx [Trk]           deriving (Show)
data Trk    = Trk [TrkSeg]        deriving (Show)
data TrkSeg = TrkSeg [TrkPt]      deriving (Show)
data TrkPt  = TrkPt Double Double deriving (Show)

parseGpx =
  getChildren >>> isElem >>> hasName "gpx" >>>
  getChildren >>> isElem >>> hasName "trk" >>>
  parseGpxTrk >>> arr Gpx

parseGpxTrk = undefined
parseGpxTrkSegs = undefined
```

You can see that it's incomplete, but it should still type-check. Unfortunately, I'm already running into an error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Trk’ with ‘[Trk]’
Expected type: Trk -> Gpx
  Actual type: [Trk] -> Gpx
In the first argument of ‘arr’, namely ‘Gpx’
In the second argument of ‘(>>>)’, namely ‘arr Gpx’
```

What this error says is that I'm trying to pass each matched item from the `parseGpxTrk` arrow through the `arr Gpx` constructor, but what I actually want is to pass the entire list of matches through the `arr Gpx` constructor.

So, how do I get `HXT` (or arrows in general?) to pass the matches as a *list* through my `arr Gpx` constructor instead of passing each entry in the list through the `arr Gpx` constructor?

Comment: You could use `XmlPickler` to do this if you want to model the full grammar of a GPX file, since `XmlPickler` is designed to not ignore extra content.  There are other ways if you don't want all the information from the file, but I can put an example using `XmlPickler` as an answer if you'd like, using only the subset of the GPX grammar you've defined in your data types.

Comment: Actually, I was able to compile your code as is.  I had to put a type signature on `parseGpx` of `ArrowXml cat => cat XmlTree Gpx`, but it seemed to work just fine for me.

Comment: Why did GHC incorrectly infer the type though? Is this a GHC bug?

Comment: So does this mean my code is actually right? I intend to get back a Gpx [Trk].

Comment: @bheklilr I'd like to use the primitives instead of the picklers if possible. I'm hoping at this point that someone can complete the basics of the code for me to demonstrate how to actually implement it. `HXT` sure is one mysterious, poorly documented beast.

Comment: @Mokosha I'm guessing the monomorphism restriction.

Comment: @Ana The type will be `ArrowXml cat => cat XmlTree Gpx`, so you'll still have to run it using something like `runX` to get an actual `Gpx` out of it.

Comment: @bheklilr I've explored it a bit more and now I think that adding the type actually fools the compiler into accepting the code, but it is not correct. This is because HXT returns lists of items through the arrows (like the `List` monad). If I pass the data through `arr Gpx`, it should apply `Gpx` to every item, not apply `Gpx` to the list of items. So the error is correct. In which case, my original question stands, which is how do I pass the list of items returned through a single arrow (the `Gpx` constructor) instead of passing each item through the `Gpx` constructor. Updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that seems pretty good to me

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}

import Data.Maybe
import Text.Read
import Text.XML.HXT.Core
import Control.Applicative

data Gpx    = Gpx [Trk]           deriving (Show)
data Trk    = Trk [TrkSeg]        deriving (Show)
data TrkSeg = TrkSeg [TrkPt]      deriving (Show)
data TrkPt  = TrkPt Double Double deriving (Show)
```

The trickiest one is probably the `parseTrkPt` because in order to do it right you have to handle parsing `String`s to `Double`, which can fail.  I've made the decision to have it return a `Maybe TrkPt` instead, and then handle that further down the line:

```hs
elemsNamed :: ArrowXml cat => String -> cat XmlTree XmlTree
elemsNamed name = isElem >>> hasName name

parseTrkPt :: ArrowXml cat => cat XmlTree (Maybe TrkPt)
parseTrkPt = elemsNamed "trkpt" >>>
    proc trkpt -> do
        lat <- getAttrValue "lat" -< trkpt
        lon <- getAttrValue "lon" -< trkpt
        returnA -< TrkPt <$> readMaybe lat <*> readMaybe lon
```

I've also used the `proc` syntax here because I think it comes out a lot cleaner.  The `TrkPt <$> readMaybe lat <*> readMaybe lon` has the type `Maybe TrkPt` and will return `Nothing` if either of the `readMaybe`s returns `Nothing`.  We can now aggregate all the successful results:

```hs
parseTrkSeg :: (ArrowXml cat, ArrowList cat) => cat XmlTree TrkSeg
parseTrkSeg =
    elemsNamed "trkseg" >>>
    (getChildren >>> parseTrkPt >>. catMaybes) >. TrkSeg
```

The parentheses are important here, it took me a while to figure that part out.  Depending on where you place the parens you'll get different results, such as `[TrkSeg [TrkPt a b], TrkSeg [TrkPt c d]]` instead of `[TrkSeg [TrkPt a b, TrkPt c d]]`.  The next to parsers are both straightforward following a similar pattern:

```hs
parseTrk :: ArrowXml cat => cat XmlTree Trk
parseTrk =
    elemsNamed "trk" >>>
    (getChildren >>> parseTrkSeg) >. Trk

parseGpx :: ArrowXml cat => cat XmlTree Gpx
parseGpx =
    elemsNamed "gpx" >>>
    (getChildren >>> parseTrk) >. Gpx
```

Then you can run it quite simply, although you'll have to still drill passed the root element:

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do
    gpxs <- runX $ readDocument [withRemoveWS yes] "ana.gpx"
                >>> getChildren
                >>> parseGpx
    -- Pretty print the document
    forM_ gpxs $ \(Gpx trks) -> do
        putStrLn "GPX:"
        forM_ trks $ \(Trk segs) -> do
            putStrLn "\tTRK:"
            forM_ segs $ \(TrkSeg pts) -> do
                putStrLn "\t\tSEG:"
                forM_ pts $ \pt -> do
                    putStr "\t\t\t"
                    print pt
```

The trick is to use the methods in the `ArrowList` typeclass, notably `>.` which has the type `a b c -> ([c] -> d) -> a b d`.  It aggregates the elements from the `ArrowList`, passes it to a function that converts it to a new type, then outputs a new `ArrowList` on that new type `d`.

If you want you can even abstract this a bit for the last 3 parsers:

```hs
nestedListParser :: ArrowXml cat => String -> cat XmlTree a -> ([a] -> b) -> cat XmlTree b
nestedListParser name subparser constructor
    =   elemsNamed name
    >>> (getChildren >>> subparser)
    >.  constructor

parseTrkSeg :: (ArrowXml cat, ArrowList cat) => cat XmlTree TrkSeg
parseTrkSeg = nestedListParser "trkseg" (parseTrkPt >>. catMaybes) TrkSeg

parseTrk :: ArrowXml cat => cat XmlTree Trk
parseTrk = nestedListParser "trk" parseTrkSeg Trk

parseGpx :: ArrowXml cat => cat XmlTree Gpx
parseGpx = nestedListParser "gpx" parseTrk Gpx
```

This might come in handy if you want to complete the rest of the grammar of a GPX file.

Comment: That's it! As you pointed out, the trick is `>.`, which I never knew about before. Thank you very much for working this out.

Comment: @Ana In particular you are interested in the functions in `ArrowList`, there are a couple in there that are useful.  I also used `>>.` with `catMaybes` since it's designed to transform the entire list, preserving the `ArrowList`'s structure.  There are some other useful combinators in there too that you may find useful for parsing in the future.